# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write data to firestore by using cloud function this my code

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


exports.addfield = functions.firestore
  .document('userInfo/DsJcWyIwSDkf0BYTFBq9xfXkzGK7')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        });
```

void

```
Future<void> addfield() async {
      HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addfield');
      await callable.call();
      print('Success');
    }
```

when I call my function

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND

Comment: Looks like you didn't install the firebase-functions module into your cloud functions project.

Comment: how to install it?

Comment: the code in this page works fine ..  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/

Comment: but I want to write to document in firestore

Comment: I'll leave this here for other people running into this error: make sure that if you host your function in a certain region (`functions.region("xyz").https.onCall(`) to also call it in this region: `FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'xyz').httpsCallable(`. Otherwise, you will get the same error.

Comment: @Finni The GOAT answer, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[onCreate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) is not a callable function, it is triggered when a document is created. The callable function is defined like this:

```
exports.addfield = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

See [Call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for details.

To create a document there is no need for functions, see [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).